VS Code formatting for Firebase NPM ES Linter
I'm working on a Firebase Cloud Functions project and I have the linter on. It feels like a massive waste of time correcting spaces to exact indents, especially when VS Code's default formatting makes the code simply look nice. Right now it seems like my options are either that, or turning off the linter.
In my package.json I currently have this:
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",

And I figured I could change it by changing it to this:
"lint": "eslint",

And that let me just use VS Code's formatting. However, the console sometimes gives me trouble deploying warning me that there might be syntax issues, so I feel like the linter is there for a reason. Google's own Firebase tutorials encouraged having the linter on as well.
Is there a VS Code setup or extension that will format spacing as the linter desires?

eslint is extremely customizable.  You can configure it to use whatever rules you want.  You have no obligation to use any of the settings that might be taken by default.  Also, if you're looking for programming tools, and web search is the best first place to start.  Requests for external resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
